# cant dismiss MFMailComposeViewController shown by clicking mail link in UITextVIew (iOS 8 beta bug)

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, ios8

**This turned out to be due to bug in iOS 8 beta. I have reported it via bug number 17318153**

I'm setting an email address to a UITextField. The intent is for iOS to see its an email address and, if the user taps it, display an instance of `MFMailComposeViewController` to send an email (which it does).

However, if the user then taps cancel, the `MFMailComposeViewController` is not being dismissed. I tried setting my viewController as a `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` and overriding `mailComposeController: didFinishWithResult: error:` but it's not being called. Seemingly, the delegate for the MFMailComposeViewController that is displayed when the url is tapped is not set to self.

How can I make the cancel button in the `MFMailComposeViewController` actually dismiss the view controller that is displayed?

My .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface AboutUsViewController : UIViewController<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>{

    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
    IBOutlet UITextView *companyName;
    IBOutlet UITextView *phoneNumber;
    IBOutlet UITextView *emailAddress;
    IBOutlet UITextView *aboutUsField;

}
@end
```

In .m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        emailAddress.text=@"support@email.com";
}



- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Close the Mail Interface
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Is this iOS8 beta 1? If so, it's a known issue.

Comment: Ahh, it is indeed. I just assumed I was doing something wrong. Throw up an answer and ill accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known iOS8 beta 1 issue. Make sure to open a bug report with Apple and post the bug report number here so people can duplicate.

Comment: Is it possible to report a bug outside of iOS 8 itself? I tried with the `Bug Reporter` but its been saying "sending" for almost 10 minutes

Comment: reported it via bug number 17318153

Comment: Indeed, sorry I always forget to do it when someone answers before it'll let me accept it