# MFMailComposeViewController in Swift

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, swift, ios8, mfmailcomposer

This is sample code:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBAction func showEmail(sender : AnyObject) {
        var emailTitle = "Test Email"
        var messageBody = "This is a test email body"
        var toRecipents = ["a.nakhimov@gmail.com"]
        var mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mc.setSubject(emailTitle)
        mc.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)
        mc.setToRecipients(toRecipents)

        self.presentViewController(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func mailComposeController(controller:MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result:MFMailComposeResult, error:NSError) {
        switch result {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog("Mail cancelled")
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog("Mail saved")
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog("Mail sent")
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog("Mail sent failure: %@", [error.localizedDescription])
        default:
            break
        }
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

In function mailComposeController I get an error on every ***case*** expression:

**Could not find an overload '~=' that accepts the supplied arguments.**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried to convert the `switch` cases into _Swift_-conform? like `case MFMailComposeResult.Cancelled:` ect...? I could not find the reference about this `enum` in _Swift_, so my idea would rather be a question than a pure solution.

Comment: Just tried: MFMailComposeResult.Type does not have a member named 'Canceled', etc.

Comment: hint: wherever possible one should use `let` instead of `var`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I compared `MFMailComposeResult` documentation on both Xcode 5 and Xcode 6.
In Swift, `MFMailComposeResult` is a struct

```
struct MFMailComposeResult {
    init(_ value: CUnsignedInt) // available in iPhone 3.0
    var value: CUnsignedInt
}
```

with `MFMailComposeResultCancelled` as a constant of type `MFMailComposeResult`:

```
var MFMailComposeResultCancelled: MFMailComposeResult { get }
```

while it's an enum in Objective-C:

```
 enum MFMailComposeResult {
    MFMailComposeResultCancelled,
    MFMailComposeResultSaved,
    MFMailComposeResultSent,
    MFMailComposeResultFailed
};
typedef enum MFMailComposeResult MFMailComposeResult;   // available in iPhone 3.0
```

In order to make your code work, you will have to compare their values which are `CUnsignedInt`.

So you will have to type the following code:

```
func mailComposeController(controller:MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result:MFMailComposeResult, error:NSError) {
    switch result.value {
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled.value:
        println("Mail cancelled")
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved.value:
        println("Mail saved")
    case MFMailComposeResultSent.value:
        println("Mail sent")
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed.value:
        println("Mail sent failure: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    default:
        break
    }
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: When I push the button, the function showEmail is executed and appears the form for send email. If I click "Send", then everything works fine - mail is sent, then the function mailComposeController is executed. NSLog displays the label "Mail sent" and the initial screen reappears.

If I'm in the dialog box of send mail, click "Cancel" button, then dialogue does not disappear, function mailComposeController does not work, two buttons - "Send" and "Cancel", becoming gray color and so it stays.

What wrong?

Comment: It seems to be a bug since first beta, you can see it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218708/cant-dismiss-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-shown-by-clicking-mail-link-in-uitextvi?rq=1)

Comment: @AudreySobgouZebaze. Your association of MFComposeResult as struct in iOS8 and enum in iOS7 is not quite correct.    MFMailComposeResult is an enum in Objective-C and it is now a struct in Swift (regardless of the OS version, or SDK: iOS 7/iOS 8)...  e

Comment: In Swift 2.1+ use "rawValue" (UInt32) instead of "value"

Answer (score 19):

in Swift 2.0 do this:

```
func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
        switch result.rawValue {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled.rawValue:
            print("Mail cancelled")
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved.rawValue:
            print("Mail saved")
        case MFMailComposeResultSent.rawValue:
            print("Mail sent")
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed.rawValue:
            print("Mail sent failure: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        default:
            break
        }
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

In swift 3.0 -> Syntax Change

```
func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
                           didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {

    switch result.rawValue {
    case MFMailComposeResult.Cancelled.rawValue:
        print("Mail cancelled")
    case MFMailComposeResult.Saved.rawValue:
        print("Mail saved")
    case MFMailComposeResult.Sent.rawValue:
        print("Mail sent")
    case MFMailComposeResult.Failed.rawValue:
        print("Mail sent failure: %@", [error!.localizedDescription])
    default:
        break
    }
    // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In swift 3, you can use this clear code:

```
 @IBAction func sendMail(_ sender: Any) {

        print(MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail())
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mail.setToRecipients(["test@test.com"])
            mail.setMessageBody("<p>This is test Mail!</p>", isHTML: true)

            present(mail, animated: true)
        } else {
             let email = "test@test.com"
             if let url = URL(string: "mailto:\(email)") {
             UIApplication.shared.open(url)
             }

        }


    }

    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
        switch result {
        case .cancelled:
            print("Mail cancelled")
        case .saved:
            print("Mail saved")
        case .sent:
            self.allertInfo(_title: "Mail Info", _message: "Mail is sent successfuly", _actionTitle: "OK")
            print("Mail sent")
        case .failed:
            self.allertInfo(_title: "Mail Info", _message: "Mail isn't sent.",
_actionTitle: "OK")
            print("Mail sent failure: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        default:
            break
        }

    }

    func allertInfo(_title:String, _message:String, _actionTitle:String) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: _title, message: _message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: _actionTitle, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Answer (score -7):

In addition to using `.value`, don't forget to add to `break` to each `case` statement, see Apple's official version: https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/samplecode/MessageComposer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010161

Comment: Swift does not require break