# Share Images button

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

i have created library photo in my App and i want to put a button to share the image by email. 
Can someone help me with that?

i have tried this but this one is for tex:

```
     let firstActivityItem = "your text here"

    let secondActivityItem : NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "your link here")!

    let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
        activityItems: [firstActivityItem, secondActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)

    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
        UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
        UIActivityTypePrint,
        UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
        UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
        UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
        UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
        UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
        UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo
    ]
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24311073/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-swift

Comment: Thanks Max, I tried but it doesnt work, do you have a clear code in swift?

Answer (score 0):

Use `MFMailComposeViewController` if you want to share by email only.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12210684/3950397) on how to attach an image to it.

Comment: I tried but it doesnt work, it gives error.. do you have a complete swift code?

Comment: It doesnt attach the picture on email, cause i want to select the picture from my gallery and send by email, the problem is it doesnt select the email to send.

Comment: You will have to load image via UIImagePicker and then use MFMailComposeViewController.